# How could I display in my front a back request?

Tags: reactjs, mongoose, frontend, backend

I've created my backend and it works. I tested different Axios requests in order to create a form.
In my React front project, I created a POST axios request, I console.log(response.data) and I got an object with the id, the title and questions.

I am stuck because I don't know how I could display the data of the object in my front.

Here is my front React code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

const NewForm = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      if (data.length === 0) {
        const response = await axios.post(
          "https://back-formnest-lereacteur.herokuapp.com/form/create",
          {
            title: "Your event",
          }
        );
        console.log(response.data);
        setData(response.data);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [data]);

  return (
I am completely stuck here to display the data of my backend in my front
```

This is my backend code:

```
const express = require("express");

const router = express.Router();

const Form = require("../models/Form");


router.post("/form/create", async (req, res) => {
  try {

    if (req.fields.title) {
      const newForm = new Form({
        title: req.fields.title,

      });


      await newForm.save();
      return res.json(newForm);
    } else {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: "Missing parameters" });
    }
  } catch (e) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: e.message });
  }

});
```

This is my console.log(response.data) I want to display in my front React page: 
[image: console.log(reponse.data)]

[image: screen shot of bugs]

I edited my code and I got an error:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
/* import { Link } from "react-router-dom"; */
import axios from "axios";

const NewForm = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      if (data.length === 0) {
        const response = await axios.post(
          "https://back.herokuapp.com/form/create",
          {
            title: "Nouveau formulaire",
          }
        );
        console.log(response.data);
        setData(response.data);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [data]);

  return (
    <>
      <div>My forms</div>

      <div>
        {data && (
          <>
            <p>{data.title}</p>
            {data.questions.map((question, index) => (
              <div> {question} </div>
            ))}
          </>
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default NewForm;
```

[image: screen shot of the error]

Hi Guys,

I updated my code but I have still an error code (TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined)

```
   <>
      <div>My forms</div>

      <div>
        {data && (
          <>
            <p>{data.title}</p>
            {data.questions.length &
              data.questions.map((question, index) => {
                return <p key={index}>{question}</p>;
              })}
          </>
        )}
      </div>
    </>
```

I updated again my code, I succeeded only to display the title of my form but I did not succeed to display the data included in my question array. I have a "0" which appears instead of my data. Please help

```
return (
    <>
      <div>My forms </div>

      <div>
        {data && data.questions && (
          <>
            <div>{data.title} </div>

            {data.questions.length &
              data.questions.map((question, index) => {
                return <p key={index}>{question}</p>;
              })}
          </>
        )}
      </div>


    </>
```

I updated again, same error appears:

```
return (
    <>
      <div>My forms </div>

      <div>
        {data &&
          data.questions &&
          data.questions.length(
            <>
              <div>{data.title} </div>

              {data.questions.map((question, index) => {
                return <p key={index}>{question}</p>;
              })}
            </>
          )}
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you've done the hard part!

now just `.map` over the question array if you want to display them out?

```
<div>
 {data.questions.map((question => (
    <div> {question.title} </div>
 ))}
</div>
```

I've only done a simple example but of course you can display as much or as little as you want

of course anything in state you can render. so if you want to display title do:

`{data.title}` wherever pleases you

Comment: thank you for your feedback and help. I succeeded to display the tittle of my form but I would like to display all the object not just the questions. How could I do please ?

Comment: Display them all via `data.` then the name of the property. If it’s an array you’ll need to use the map function I showed data.id in the same way will show the id

Comment: thanks you but I have an error in my front when I map questions array
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: Post what you have so far and we’ll go through it. Map of undefined means that the thing you are mapping over is undefined

Comment: @Yoni change it do `data && data.questions.length (`

Comment: Thanks Red for the update. I posted my code updated but I got still an error : typeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: @Yoni how about `data && data.questions && data.questions.length ` ?

Comment: I got a TypeError: "data.questions.length is not a function

Comment: why are you using it like a function?

Comment: I updated again like you recommend me. I got the same error

Comment: I want to display all my array "questions". For info, my mongoose model is as follows:         const Form = mongoose.model("Form", {
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },

  questions: [
    {
      title: {
        type: String,
      },

      answers: {
        title: {
          type: Array,
        },
      },
    },
  ],
});

Comment: When I remove data.questions.length, I got only the display of {data.title} and not the remaining, i.e the array "questions"

Comment: @Yoni are you able to do a codesandbox? then it'll be easy to show you :)

Comment: thanks Red. I will do a codesandbox. Please confirm me your username to share the code. I do not see Red Baron in the suggestions when I want to share. I saw e-Baron

Comment: you can just save it and post the link in here and I will be able to access it. thanks @Yoni

Comment: https://c8umv.csb.app/ @red baron. Do you need my mongoose model  too ?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/c8umv?file=/src/App.js @red baron is it ok ? I copied the link

Comment: yes I see now. but you have no questions coming back from the response, that is why it's not showing them? otherwise code looks fine

Comment: I added a question thanks to Postman and I see them in my MongoDB. But I am not able to see it in my front. What is the solution ?

Comment: but in your postman request you can see that `questions` is an empty array too. so I'm not sure of the problem? are you sure you're requesting the right path?

Comment: my mongoDB model is as follows : const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Form = mongoose.model("Form", {
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },

  questions: [
    {
      title: {
        type: String,
      },

      answers: {
        title: {
          type: Array,
        },
      },
    },
  ],
});

module.exports = Form;      Answers is an empty array, not the questions. I see that Postman added questions

Comment: yes that looks fine but my point is. it's returning 0 questions. i.e. `questions: [ ]` is coming back from the response. that's even happening in Postman. you need to make sure when you make your request that questions are being returned. this is a server problem not frontend problem. frontend is only a problem if we get questions back from the response and then they don't get rendered but in this case it's not showing any because there arent any

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your backend responds with an object, so here is how you could go about it.

1) Change your initinal state to undefined like this.

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
```

to

```
const [data, setData] = useState(undefined);
```

Then you can use it in the display like this

```
return (
    <div>
        {data && (
            <>
                <p>{data._id}</p>
                <p>{data.title}</p>
                {data.question.length && data.question.map((question,idx) => {
                    // this is assuming that each question is just a string and not an object
                 return   (<p key={idx}>{question}</p>)
                })}
            </>
        )}
    </div>
)
```

Comment: thanks Shmili for your answer, I tried it but I got 2 bugs in the console. I want to display all the object with the title, the questions and the answers included please. I shared a screen shot of the bug in the edited version of my question (last image)

Comment: Yoni, I updated the answer, hopefully it works now, I changed this line `<p key={idx}>{question}</p>` to `return   (<p key={idx}>{question}</p>)`

Comment: Thanks Shmili for the update. I posted my code updated but I got still an error : typeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: Did you change `const [data, setData] = useState([]);` to `const [data, setData] = useState(undefined);` ?

Comment: Also you may want to to a check before mapping the questions as well, change `{data.questions.length && data.questions.map((question,idx) => {` to `{data.questions && data.questions.length && data.questions.map((question,idx) => {`

Comment: And also you need a double `&&`  when checking for an `and` condition in JavaScript.

Comment: Did you change const [data, setData] = useState([]); to const [data, setData] = useState(undefined). I got an error here